# Breaking up a 3D geometric object near bottlenecks and minimizing the creation/destruction of holes

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algorithms, 3d, volume

I have a geometric object composed of individual voxels that I've identified as a 'cluster.' The cluster was identified using a flood-fill algorithm assuming face-connectedness.  I have an analysis that I'd like to do on this cluster (and other *much* larger clusters) which is NP-hard.  This algorithm can only handle up to $N_{points}$.

So, I'd like to break up the volume into the minimum number of parts (i.e. $M_{parts}$) such that no chunk/part has more than $N_{points}$.  The caveat, however, is that I'd like to intelligently cut up my cluster such that I minimize the number of holes that I create and destroy.  These holes are relevant for my analysis algorithm.

For instance, there is an obvious bottleneck on the lower right side of the image.  That would be a perfect location to cut.

Obviously, this is challenging because I'm trying to optimize three competing variables: size, number of holes and number of chunks.

**QUESTION** : Are there any canonical algorithms to do such a task?

[image]

Comment: One approach is to do one or more passes of removing surface voxels, until the set is no longer connected. (You can use a disjoint-set data structure to efficiently monitor changes in connectedness/clustering.) The bottlenecks are then among the removed voxels. You can, for example, re-add the removed voxels back to the closest clusters, to find your desired sub-sets. Note, however, that this does not explicitly find the bottlenecks; it only subdivides the set along the bottlenecks. (Which is why this is a comment and not an answer.)